# Use mail command in terminal to send emails and specify From address

Tags: email, csh

I have tried to send thousands of emails through running a csh script to execute the "mail" command. But all my emails were blocked by the recipient. I was told that the blocking reason is because of the workstation domain (kichisatoru@Sky.local), which is not a real domain (e.g. xx@gmail.com). How can I fix this issue, so the recipient can receive my emails in the standard way?

My csh:

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach eml (`ls *.eml`)
    mail recipient@edu < $eml
    echo $eml sent...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed! I have found a very detailed manual online http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-mac-os-x-el-capitan/